# wkhtmltopdf to save file in password protected directory

Tags: java, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, outputstream, html-to-pdf

How can i save pdf file in a password protected shared drive using wkhtmltopdf. I am able to save on local server on unprotected directory.
Below code works fine for local unprotected directory.

```
Pdf pdf = new Pdf();
pdf.addPageFromString(receiptString);
pdf.saveAs(filename);
```

I tried accessing the shared directory using SmbFile authentication but how to save my pdf there.

```
 NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(domain, username, password);
    SmbFile file = new SmbFile(filename, auth);
```